# Is the TV show "Gotham" on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is the TV show Gotham on topic? In season 1, only one episode contains material that is seriously sci-fi in nature, which according to current guidelines only makes that episode on-topic, not the series. Or is it on-topic because Batman makes all Batman-related works blanket on-topic?

Comment: For better or worse, the Nolan-Verse has been deemed on-topic. If that one is on topic, then I'd say Gotham is as well.

Comment: @phantom42 See also S1 of *Arrow*.

Comment: Our canonical "what's on topic" answer from many ages ago included the fact that works in an "on-topic setting" are on-topic even if they contain no direct sci-fi elements themselves, which puts basically everything based on DC comics on-topic.

Comment: @JasonBaker Why did you erase your answer? Even if the show changed enough for it to be irrelevant, I think it was still an interesting part of the discussion.

Comment: It covers _Batman,_ a **stated** comic book character who has touched on nearly _All_ genre elements. Considering it also includes elements like high-concept/ theoretical technology, meta-humans showcasing at least _enhanced_ abilities, and some aspects of mysticism, I'd think it's pretty much fair game.

Answer (score 15):

**TL;DR - *Gotham* should be on-topic because being in the "superhero" genre isn't judged purely by content, but by association.**

---

**Full answer**

Our Help Center doesn't, in fact, mention comic books or superheroes at all as part of our accepted topics. This is, I guess, because they're accepted as a sub-genre of SF or Fantasy (even though I believe they're a genre of their own). As such, it's a bit unclear where to draw the line between the heroic and the superheroic.

However, this vague line, as drawn, often puts the clearly heroic as on-topic, with Batman and the *Arrow* TV show (in its earlier seasons) seen as clearly on-topic despite having very few elements of super-science or unexplained phenomena. This is, I believe, because Batman and the Arrow are clearly in the "superhero comics" genre, not necessarily because of their actual *content*, but because of history and association - they share a history and stories with the clearly SFnal Superman, for instance.

This is why I believe *Gotham* *should* be on topic, just like other genre-free Batman stories or spin-offs. Because it's still *Batman*, in a variant of the Batman universe, which is accepted as on-topic here.

It's true that if you changed the names you'll just have a non-genre cop show, but *the names are important*. They're what draw a lot of viewers. They add a layer of meaning or people familiar with those names and their (alternate) history. **It's a show watched by our site's members, *because* of its on-topic association**.

Comment: No superheroes in gotham to date its similar to james bond, if no sci-fi fantasy elements are in other series that are sci-fi fantasy series as a whole, the specific titles are offtopic, i dont see why comic universe is the exception to this rule

Comment: James Bond is an off topic series that occasionally has on topic issues. Batman is the other way around.

Comment: It seems odd to me that we should deem a work on-topic solely because it's an adaptation of an on-topic work. To my mind, *Batman* comics are on-topic not because of any special property of Batman himself, but because he's part of a universe where aliens, advanced technology, and magical/fantastical elements exist and are natural. I'm fine with that as a definition, but *Gotham* doesn't have that. It just has a cop named James Gordon and a rich kid named Bruce Wayne who probably needs some therapy

Comment: @JasonBaker But Gotham does not exist in a vacuum. It livesnon references and allusions to the rest of the Batman franchise, in addition to its own merits. Otherwise, why make it a Batman show?

Comment: Sure, and as soon as the show's producers decide to bring in some of the SFF elements of the Batman mythos, I'll be 100% behind it being on-topic. But, as important as the names and the links to the existing canon are to the flavour of the show, using those names isn't enough to make it SFF to me. I remember ages ago reading some *Harry Potter* fanfiction where the characters are all completely normal college students, with no magic whatsoever. The issue of whether or fanfiction  is on-topic aside, should that work be on-topic solely because it invokes the symbols of *Harry Potter*?

Comment: @JasonBaker (Sorry for the delay) - Yes, I think it should be on topic, if the work is an interesting take on the HP characters and is of interest to the HP fandom. It's HP characters, in a different context. Just like an issue of Superman reimagining him as a non-powered hero would be.

Answer (score 0):

Three reasons it could be consider either fantasy or sci-fi:

1. It's based in a world/city that **does not exist in real life,** taken from a character in a *recognized* comic book that over the years has covered all elements.
2. It has human beings who are at least to *some* degree enhanced beyond human capacity, be it by science or genetics
3. It includes elements of mysticism, and if we want to get meta, even *predestination,* considering it showcases Bruce basically having little choice to deviate from the established life path of becoming an iconic vigilante... even meeting many of his enemies *before* he dons the cape and cowl.

Add in the little elements that are at least highly *unlikely* to occur in real life, and it seems to still be topic relevant.

Answer (score -3):

Gotham is on-topic because Fish can do weird stuff when she touches you.

Comment: @Downvoter: wut? Have you seen the show?

Comment: DV might be because it seems more like a comment then answer

Comment: What weird stuff can she (allegedly) do?